# Basic CSS layout issue with 960 grid system

Tags: css, 960.gs

Upon inspection of the element `<div id="wrapper">` in firebug it seems that it does not contain all the content that is nested inside it and is in fact very small.

Another issue is that `<div id="footer">` is positioned at the top of the page when inspected in firebug and I am unsure as to why.

Any help would be much appreciated. There is a link below.

http://www.the-session.co.uk/pros/

Answer (score 0):

**Define your body** `min-width:980px;`  **and clear your** `.container_12` `overflow:hidden;`

**as like this**

```
    body{
    min-width:980px;
    }
.container_12{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the floats in the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```